# Schema.org data structure for transport system

Tags: schema.org

I'm trying to classify a number of transport systems. I would like to use Schema.org markup but I can not find a category that covers these items.

I guess I need to create a custom "object". Can anyone give me a simple example of how to mark up my content?

The information could be like this:

- Item: London Underground
- City: London
- Type: Metro
- Number of lines: 10
- Number of stations: 10
- Basic fare: 1
- Schedule: 00:00 - 23:00
- …

Another one:

- Item: Barcelona Bus Network
- City: Barcelona
- Type: Bus
- Number of lines: 15
- Number of stations: 200
- …

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a custom object the way you are asking, I believe you can get by using schema.org's [Service](http://schema.org/Service) though. Schema has some more specific service types, if each transport system in your list is government maintained, then perhaps you could use [Government Service](http://schema.org/GovernmentService).

As far as how to mark up your content, you first need to decide how you want to add schema (e.g. microdata, RDFa, JSON-LD). The schema.org site has general examples that should help point you in the right direction on how to write one of those three. [Here's an example code of a general service](http://schema.org/Service#offer-3)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I might manage to do what I need by mixing or nesting schemas.

Answer (score 0):

I leave my answer, it can be useful to someone no matter how much time has passed.

The transport service has to be added under the service scheme. But if you don't want to leave out your local business, you can add that business as a service provider.

Here is an example of how it should be done.

```json
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Service",
    "provider": {
      "@type": "LocalBusiness",
      "name": "Litoral Trans"
    },
    "areaServed": {
      "@type": "Status",
      "name": "Santa Fe"
    },
    ...
}
```

You can find good examples at the end of the following link https://schema.org/Service

Comment: Thanks Lucas from the past